# Using constants in AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use constants in my routing to handle ACL of each controller. But in the `config`, constants is not made available and the injection seems broken. However, I can access the value from everywhere else in the app.

```js
var app = angular.module('myproject', [
    'ui.router'
]);

app.constant('USER_ROLES', {
    all: '*',
    admin: 'admin',
    role1: 'role1',
    role2: 'role2'
});

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, USER_ROLES) {
      console.log("Value: ", USER_ROLES);
});
```

This code produces this output into the console:

`Value:  undefined`

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a `]` somewhere

Comment: I believe constats are set after runtime so when the app is in config the constants are not set yet. i'm not sure about this but i believe they are available after your platform is ready.

Comment: Thanks @devqon I just noticed it, I cropped my snippet to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @SjoerdDeWit Constants are available into the config, this is one of the rare already-available resources at this point of the app lifecycle.

Comment: Oke thanks, leaves me to question why i've set them after the config. and i've got a question for you. Do you know if it is possible to set the constant for my api-url and use it in the config to set the default route for my httpprovider? @sweepy_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'USER_ROLES', // <-- you forgot this
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, USER_ROLES) {
      console.log("Value: ", USER_ROLES);
}]);
```

You were injecting the `USER_ROLES`, but you didn't add it to the dependencies in the array notation. Also you were missing the closing `]`

Comment: That was the first part of your answer that solved my problem, thanks @devqon!